# Fórmula para separar valores de una columna

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo, formulas

La hoja de cálculo de Google cuenta con la función SPLIT para separar valores de una cadena pero no puede utilizarse usando como argumento un rango o matriz de 1 X n o n X 1, por ejemplo A1:A3 mediante ARRAYFORMULA.

La fórmula siguiente da como resultado #VALOR

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(A1:A3,",")
```

Cuando son dos columnas, una alternativa es combinar funciones como IZQUIERDA, DERECHA, por ejemplo

```
=ArrayFormula(
   {
      IZQUIERDA(A1:A3,ENCONTRAR(",",A1:A3)-SIGNO(FILA(A1:A3))),
      DERECHA(A1:A3,LARGO(A1:A3)-ENCONTRAR(",",A1:A3))
    }
 )
```

¿Qué función se puede utilizar cuando el número de columnas es mayor para evitar tener una fórmula demasiado larga y complicada de mantener?

P.D. La hoja de cálculo de Google recientemente incorporó un comando de menú para separar texto en columnas. Esta pregunta se refiere específicamente a cómo hacer la separación usando usando fórmulas.

Comment: asociación: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26137115/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Respuesta corta

[REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=es) con una expresión regular calculada

## Ejemplo

Asumamos que los valores a separar están en A1:A3 y usan una coma como separador. La fórmula a utilizar sería:

```
=ArrayFormula(
   SI.ERROR(
     REGEXEXTRACT(
       ","&
       A1:A3,
       "^"&
       REPETIR(
         ",+[^,]+",
         COLUMNA(DESREF(A1,,,1,6))-1
       )&
       ",+([^,]+)"
     )
   )
 )
```

COLUMNA(DESREF(A1,,,1,6))-1) dentro de una función ARRAYFORMULA da como resultado {0,1,2,3,4,5} lo cual usamos para extraer, el primer, segundo, y así hasta el sexto elemento que se encuentre entre el caracter utilizado como separador, que en este caso es una coma. Para incluir más elementos cambiar el 6 por otro valor.

Nota: Se puede calcular el número de columnas pero al estar esto afectaría el desempeño de la hoja de cálculo de forma notoria cuanda se tiene un número de filas alto.

Para facilitar el mantenimiento, se puede usar la característica de [asignación de nombres a rangos](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63175?hl=es) tanto para indicar el rango con los datos a separar como indicar el separador y el límite de columnas, por ejemplo, de la siguiente forma:

```
=ArrayFormula(
  SI.ERROR(
    REGEXEXTRACT(
      separador&
      datos,
      "^"&
      REPETIR(
        separador&"+[^"&separador&"]+",
        COLUMNA(DESREF(A1,,,1,columnas))-1
      )&
      separador&
      "+([^"&separador&"]+)"
     )
   )
 )
```

## Referencias

- [Respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26138109/1595451) por [AdamL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1373663/adaml) a [ARRAYFORMULA() does not work with SPLIT()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26137115/1595451) en Stack Overflow (en inglés).
- [Split a column of strings with a single formula returning an array](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/88517/88163) en Stack Exchange Web Applications (en inglés)

Comment: Tal cual se actualizó en la [respuesta de AdamL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26138109/5290909), ahora SPLIT funciona con ARRAYFORMULA: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SPLIT(A1:A3,",")))`

Comment: ¡Esta era el hilo que pretendía encontrar! Gracias dobles. Por cierto, el año pasado me pareció no encontrar actividad reciente de AdamL, es bueno que esté activo de nuevo.