# ¿A qué se debe que REGEXEXTRACT devuelve un único valor cuando se espera que devuelva una matriz de 1 renglón y varias columnas?

Tags: regex, google-hoja-de-cálculo

La característica de manejo de matrices de las hojas de cálculo de Google resulta conveniente y combinada con las funciones que manejan expresiones regulares como REGEXMATCH y REGEXEXTRACT entre otras, lo hace especialmente útil.

Tengo un caso que en el que no sé a qué se debe que no da el resultado esperado. A continuación describo lo que estoy intentando:

**Configuración de hoja de cálculo**
Configuración regional: México (usar . como separador decimal)

**Entrada**
A1: `abcde`

**Fórmula**
B1: `=ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,{".{1}",".{2}"}))`

**Resultado esperado**
B1: `a`
B2: `ab`

**Resultado obtenido**
B1: `a`
B2:

**Solución provisional conocida**
`=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,{".{1}";".{2}"})))`

Esta pregunta también ha sido publicada en el sitio en inglés -> https://stackoverflow.com/q/42826011/1595451

Comment: Relacionado: http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/21779/65 chapó @Mariano.

Comment: asociación: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42826011/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según lo expresado por Jean-Pierre Verhulst en un caso análogo en [*REGEXEXTRACT Array Mysteriously Stopped Working Today* (Google Docs Help Forum)](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/BTkFLfPGzCM):

> El equipo está al tanto de este caso y debería solucionarse pronto.

Coincidentemente, la fecha de publicación es el 4/1/2017, la misma fecha en la que [AdamL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1373663/adaml) modificó su respuesta en [*ARRAYFORMULA() does not work with SPLIT()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26138109/5290909), explicando que:

> REGEXEXTRACT parece haber dejado de admitir un array en el segundo parámetro.

---

Podemos concluir que **se debe a una modificación en el comportamiento de ArrayFormula**, en el que se mejoró el código para permitir el uso de funciones como SPLIT con funciones sobre arrays, pero que dejó a REGEXEXTRACT sin aceptar casos concretos. Este caso ocurre particularmente con rangos que se extienden horizontalmente.

Probablemente se deba a que REGEXEXTRACT puede dar como resultado un rango variable de celdas horizontales. Cuando se utilizan grupos de captura en la expresión regular, la función devuelve una celda por cada grupo, y teniendo un array como argumento, no está definido el comportamiento que debería tener. Sin embargo, esto último es totalmente especulativo de mi parte.

Answer (score 2):

Pareciera ser un bug.

Si bien no esta explicitamente documentado el tipo de retorno en la documentación de [REGEXREXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=es), debería funcionar con [Matrices](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=es).

De hecho en la imagen podemos ver que `;` funciona, pero `,` no:

[image: Ejemplos de funciones y sus resultados]

Otra solución alternativa es crear tu propia matriz; ie: `{regexextract(A1, ".{1}"), regexextract(A1,".{2}")}`

Saludos!

Comment: La respuesta es útil porque reproduce la situación reportada y da un segunda solución alternativa. Por el momento no la acepto, por el "pareciera" y porque la pregunta todavía es muy recient.